# Defer on Load with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

How do we get this to exlcude certain plugins? i have a notification bar that shows after a few seconds but this has stoped working now?

This code set's most java scripts to defer on load but i need it to exclude two lines of code or maybe others in the future as it's working great but stopping a plugin working correctly? Here is the code:

```
// Defer Javascripts Speed up loading for external js files wait till page loads
// Defer jQuery Parsing using the HTML5 defer property
if (!(is_admin() )) {
    function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
        // return "$url' defer ";
        return "$url' defer onload='";
    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```

I need to exlcude these two lines from defer:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="somescript.js" defer="" onload="">

<script type="text/javascript" src="another.js" defer="" onload="">
```

Thanks kindly T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Defer Javascripts Speed up loading for external js files wait till page loads
// Defer jQuery Parsing using the HTML5 defer property
if (!(is_admin() )) {
  function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
    if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) || strpos( $url, 'jquery.c.js' ) || strpos( $url, 'wpfront-notification-bar.js' ) ) return $url;
    // return "$url' defer ";
    return "$url' defer onload='";
}
  add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Defer Javascripts Speed up loading for external js files wait till page loads
// Defer jQuery Parsing using the HTML5 defer property
if (!(is_admin() )) {
    function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
        if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
        if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) || strpos( $url, 'jquery.c.js' ) || strpos( $url, 'wpfront-notification-bar.js' ) ) return $url;
        return "$url' defer='defer";
    }
    add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
}
```